# Deseralize JSON where property can be of different types

Tags: c#, json, json.net

When calling an external API that returns a list and deserializing, one of the list item properties can be of type string or an object. I want to deserialize all objects to object and for strings just set the property as null. Can you do it somehow to specify the behavior of fallback in order to prevent `System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'The JSON value could not be converted to ...` exception?

```
public class ListItem 
{
    [JsonPropertyName["location"]
    public Location Location { get;set; }
}

// ...

public class Location
{
    [JsonPropertyName("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

And the API responds with:

```
[
  {
     "location": "some location",
     // ...
  },
  {
     "location":
        {
            "city": "some city",
            "city": "some country"
        }
  }
]
```

Comment: You are looking for [dynamic object](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm)

Comment: Use `JsonElement` as the type. After deserialization you can check it’s `ValueKind` property if it’s a string or object and then call `GetString` or the `Deserialize` extension method to get the actual values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Newtonsoft.Json and constructor

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

List<ListItem> locations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ListItem>>(json);

public class ListItem
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Location Location { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public ListItem(JToken location)
    {
        if (location.Type == JTokenType.String)
            Location = new Location { City = (string)location };
        else Location = location.ToObject<Location>();
    }
}
```